# how to await the functions in init method?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I want to await the function inside init state and show some loading instead when the functions are executing, but as I cant use async-await in init. How can I make to await these methods, is there any way out, if there is , can you edit my code ?

```
 void initState() {
            super.initState();
            if (mounted) {
              pageController = PageController();
        
              googleSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((account) {
                handleSignIn(account);
              }, onError: (err) {});
        
              setState(() {
                _isSplashScreen = true;
              });
              googleSignIn.signInSilently(suppressErrors: false).then((account) {
                handleSignIn(account);
                setState(() {
                  _isSplashScreen = false;
                });
              }).catchError((err) {
                print('Error signing in (silently): $err');
                setState(() {
                  _isSplashScreen = false;
                });
              });
            }
          }
    
    handleSignIn(GoogleSignInAccount account) async {
        if (mounted) {
          if (account != null) {
            await createUserInFirestore();
            setState(() {
              isAuth = true;
            });
            configurePushNotifications();
          } else {
            setState(() {
              isAuth = false;
            });
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: Use a `FutureBuilder`.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore can you edit and show me a code snippet

Comment: There is lots of documentation online on how to do it. Some of the [widget docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) including `FutureBuilder`, provide examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `WidgetsBinding` to make async-await call inside initState< 
Example :

```
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) async {
       await dummy();
    });
}
```